# How to output a text file using ZendFramework 1?

Tags: xml, zend-framework

I'm writing a ZendFramework (1.4) app in which I need to show the contents of a particular file. This is my code:

```
public function showfileAction()
{
        $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
        $configOptions = $this->getInvokeArg('bootstrap')->getOptions();

        $file = $configOptions['files']['dir'] . $this->getRequest()->getParam('file');
        if ( is_readable( $file ) ) {
            foreach ( $this->getRequest()->getParam('headers') as $h => $v ) {
                $this->getResponse()->setHeader( $h, $v );
            }
            $this->view->file_contents = file_get_contents($file);
        } else {
            $this->_redirect ('/not-found');
        }
}
```

The particular file I'm trying to show is an xml (I tried several different content types with the same result), and what I get is the contents of the file **prepended by a tab character** (!), which, in the case of xml, results in an error like this (taken from google chrome):

```
error on line 1 at column 6: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document.
```

The contents of my file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<users>
    <user>XXXX</user>
</users>
```

The result I get:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<users>
    <user>XXXX</user>
</users>
```

Here's `showfile.phtml`:

```
<?php
echo $this->file_contents;
?>
```

Comment: Allowing the file path and response headers to be set by user input seems somewhat risky...

Comment: @TimFountain yes... I see your point, I'll take a look at it, but I think I'm fine since this action is catched by a very specific routing rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to use a view script for this so I'd probably change what you have to:

```
public function showfileAction()
{
    $this->getHelper('viewRenderer')->setNoRender(true);
    $this->getHelper('layout')->disableLayout();

    $configOptions = $this->getInvokeArg('bootstrap')->getOptions();

    $file = $configOptions['files']['dir'] . $this->getRequest()->getParam('file');
    if ( is_readable( $file ) ) {
        foreach ( $this->getRequest()->getParam('headers') as $h => $v ) {
            $this->getResponse()->setHeader( $h, $v );
        }
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(file_get_contents($file));
    } else {
        $this->_redirect ('/not-found');
    }
}
```

If the stray tab is not in the XML file you're rendering, it might be being caused by white space after the closing `?>` of one of the PHP files in your app. There isn't really an easy way to find out which one - best practice is to omit the last `?>` from pure-PHP files to avoid this problem.

Another warning about security - even if you think your routing restrictions are enough, if your app still uses the default `:controller/:action` route then a user might be able to bypass that, so be careful about what you let into this controller.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll try to figure the extra tab character, that's probably the case. About the security I tried specifically the url /showfile/xx.txt and verified it's not accessible (I don't use the default route).